# Ctrl-Sでターミナルがキー入力を受けつけなくなったときの解除法

Tags: linux

LinuxのターミナルではCtrl-Sによってキー入力を受けつけなくなります。
それを解除するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-Qを入力することで解除できます。